# Image pulling script not working PHP

Tags: php

Not sure why the code below is not working, its displaying the "Else" value in the IF statement basically saying that there are no IMG tags found on the page but.. im sure they are there? any advice or guidance will be appreciated.

```
    // This variable will contain all the HTML source code of the sample page
$htmlContent = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/ken_flavius/');

var_dump($htmlContent);

// We'll add all the images in this array
$images = [];

// Instantiate a new object of class DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// Load the HTML doc into the object
$doc->loadHTML($htmlContent);

// Get all the IMG tags in the document
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

// If we get at least one result
if($elements->length > 0)
{
    // Loop on all of the IMG tags
    foreach($elements as $element)
    {
        // Get the attribute SRC of the IMG tag (this is the link of the image)
        $src = $element->getAttribute('src');

        if (strlen($src) > 0) {
            // Add the link to the array containing all the links
            array_push($images, $src);
        }

    }

    //show all links
    echo '<pre>'."\r\n";
    print_r($images);
    echo '</pre>'."\r\n";

} else {
    // No result, it means that there were no IMG tags
    echo 'no img tag found in the HTML source provided!';
}
```

Edited it to show the exact example that im using.

Comment: Show us the contents of $htmlContent

Comment: Are you sure you're getting anything back? AFAIK, you usually can't get HTML back from a secure page. Update: `var_dump($htmlContent)` is returning empty string. It seems like you want to access a user's Instagram pictures. There's a proper API for it, use that instead.

Comment: I use `var_dump($htmlContent)` and it populated the current page with the instagram page with all the images and everything else from it, so how is it returning an empty string?

Comment: If you want to interact with a social network such as Instagram, you should use their API they provide for that purpose, rather than scraping their actual website pages.

Comment: @BasitSaeed  You are right its because its 'https' but for some reason when i run var_dump it returns the page this was confusing. But thank you very much! if you would make an answer ill accept it as soon as i can.
and K CBroe, well anyway im using another site because there's a reason i'm not using the API but thanks anyway.

Comment: If you are getting some content back in `var_dump`, check if there is a `img` in there and update your answer to include the content you're getting back. I would still recommend you to use the proper Instagram API to fetch data the actual way instead of scraping their website.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url="http://example.com"; 
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```